# ORA-01403 _sometimes_ while reading a file on Oracle 18c

Tags: oracle, oracle-18c

Edit:
We just checked: it also happens in on-premise Oracle 18c, latest patchset and everything.

In Oracle PL/SQL we are opening and reading a file. The file exists, we are getting data, but then *sometimes* while reading, the process gets killed with an `ORA-01403: no data found`.

Funny thing is: we restart the exact same procedure with the exact same file and it runs flawlessly, just in 1 out of maybe 25 runs, we're getting the error.

This problem first occured after we migrated from on-premise Oracle to Amazon RDS Oracle 18c, never before.

Is this some strange Oracle 18c memory/buffer problem? We can't wrap our heads around this issue...

Comment: check the rds logs, thisn looks more like a problem in rds

Comment: Nothing to see there, but I edited the post, it also happens on-premise. Not with Oracle 12c, though

Comment: Rather difficult to say when we don't know the context in which the error was thrown.  You say "while reading a file".  So, is this an external table? utl_file?  Is this in a pl/sql procedure? A sql script? An external language like java or c#, or such?

Comment: Just a file, text, reading the lines using `UTL_FILE.GET_LINE` to insert the values into the DB.

Comment: OK, on re reading I see that (or did you update the question with that info?  :-)  Still a  bit un-clear if this happens when you have a file vs. when you do not.  Could it be that the file exists but has zero length?

Comment: No, like I wrote: _we restart the exact same procedure with the exact same file and it runs flawlessly, just in 1 out of maybe 25 runs, we're getting the error._ Same file, same procedure, same everything